# Не отменяется запрос на сервер при использовании abortcontroller.abort()

Tags: javascript, ajax, request, promise, fetch

Имеется строка поиска при вводе данных в которую сразу уходит запрос на сервер, без нажатия пользователем клавиши Enter. В приложении реализован debouncing, для того, чтобы не отправлять запрос при каждом введенном символе, но тем не мене хочу в том числе отменять запрос который уже ушел на сервер, в случае если пользователь изменит значение в поле, когда время debouncing'а уже прошло. Необходимость отменять запросы появилась впервые, решил для этого использовать новый для себя функционал AbortController, но по какой-то причине он не отрабатывает.

Ниже пример моей реализации, метод onSearchLineValueChane запускается при изменении значения в строке поиска и принимает на вход введенный пользователем текст. На сервере установил таймаут на 10 секунд, чтобы он не отвечал мгновенно и была возможность протестировать реализацию. При первичном вводе данных в поле, запрос уходит и висит в состоянии panding, при повторном вводе вызывается this._abortController.abort(), в консоли появляется сообщение aborted, уходит второй запрос, но при этом первый не становится canceled, а так и продолжает ждать ответа сервера, выполняется до конца и соответственно срабатывает его promise (ниже привожу скриншот Network).

Подскажите пожалуйста, что делаю не так? по какой причине запрос может не отменяться если событие abort на сигнале произошло, даже eventListener на signal отработал и сообщение ушло в консоль. Заранее благодарен за любую помощь!

```
_onSearchLineValueChange(value){
    this._searchModel.setSearchText(value);
    if(value){
        if(this._currentRequest){
            this._abortController.abort();
        }
        this._abortController = new AbortController();
        const signal = this._abortController.signal;
        signal.addEventListener("abort", ()=>{console.log("aborted")});
        const api = new API();
        this._currentRequest = api.getData(this._searchArea, value, signal)
            .then(data => {
                this._onDataReceiving(data);
                this._currentRequest = null;
            });
    }else{
        this._onGlobalSearchClired();
    }
}
```

Метод getData объекта api

```
    getData(searchArea, searchData, filters = false, signal){
    let queryParams = {area: searchArea, searchData: searchData, dataFilters: filters}

    return fetch(
        'http://мой_урл',
        {
            method: 'POST',
            signal: signal,
            mode: 'cors',
            cache: 'no-cache',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            redirect: 'follow',
            referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer'
            body: JSON.stringify(queryParams)
        }
    ).then(result => result.json());
}
```

Скриншот консоли
[image: Вкладка Network в консоли]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас проблема не в отмене, а в вызове функции `getData`. В ней 4 аргумент - `signal`.

Вы вызываете и передает `signal` третьим аргументом `api.getData(this._searchArea, value, signal)`.

Comment: Это фиаско...Спасибо Вам, Степан!)